# AWK record separator set to empty line not working

Tags: bash, awk, multiline, separator

I am trying to write a simple AWK script which uses empty lines as record separator. I reproduced on my PC the example from the GNU AWK manual [Multiple-Line Records](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html). I copy the code below:

```
# addrs.awk --- simple mailing list program

# Records are separated by blank lines.
# Each line is one field.
BEGIN { RS = "" ; FS = "\n" }

{
      print "Name is:", $1
      print "Address is:", $2
      print "City and State are:", $3
      print ""
}
```

Input is:

```
Jane Doe
123 Main Street
Anywhere, SE 12345-6789

John Smith
456 Tree-lined Avenue
Smallville, MW 98765-4321
```

Files are created on UNIX system.

Required output is:

```
Name is: Jane Doe
Address is: 123 Main Street
City and State are: Anywhere, SE 12345-6789

Name is: John Smith
Address is: 456 Tree-lined Avenue
City and State are: Smallville, MW 98765-4321
```

Instead, I get a result which is different from the expected one. What  I get is:

```
Name is: Jane Doe
Address is: 123 Main Street
City and State are: Anywhere, SE 12345-6789
```

Does anybody know why I am getting the wrong result? AWK finds only 1 record instead of 2, do you know why?

Comment: your current output looks correct. Please update your Q with 2 sample input records AND your required output from at least one of those records. Also, if Windows was involved creating your datafile, clean it up w `dos2unix datafile`. Good luck.

Comment: Tried it, works as it should on OS X

Comment: Works fine on my old-as-the-hills SUSE box

Comment: Try printing `$0`; that'll tell you what `awk` thinks is in the record.  Which platform are you testing on?  Are you using GNU `awk`?

Comment: I'm going to second the DOS line endings comment. I expect that's the issue here. Try the `dos2unix` (or similar) idea.

Comment: I'm on Mint 17.2 and yes, it's GNU AWK. Printing `$0` shows the whole input. As wrote on the last line AWK finds 1 record only!
The file has been created in UNIX, running dos2unix has no effect!

Comment: If you look at the hex what characters do you see between `6789` and `John`?

Comment: I see `0a 0a`, which is correctly `\n\n`

Comment: Run `awk '{print NR, NF, "<" $0 ">"}' file` on your input file and edit your question to show the result.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Do you mean to replace the prints with your print?

Comment: Strange I did copy and paste again from the website and it worked O.o... I swear, I got that wrong output previously.

Comment: @mike the purpose would have been to see what awk thinks the contents of your input file were, line by line and field by field, but it looks like it's too late to debug that now.

Answer (score 2):

This is to confirm that:

(1) the given program works properly using `awk version 20070501`, `gawk`, or `mawk`, provided the input file has bare newline ('\n') line endings (as opposed to CR LF).

(2) if the input is a DOS text file, then the result is as the OP stated.

Also, if the input file is a DOS text file, an alternative to `dos2unix` is to use `tr` as illustrated here:

```
$ tr -d '\r' < input.dos.txt | awk ....
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. Still don't know why I did again copy and paste and it worked...